# continue to print 100 lines at a time if user enters input

Tags: c#, file, input, io

I have a console application that prints lines from text file containing lines (thousands) of text.

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(__inputfile))
{
    string nextline = tr.ReadLine();
    while (nextline != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nextline);
        nextline = tr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I want to change this so that it only prints 100 lines, asks the user to hit Enter before printing the next 100 lines, and so on and so forth

```
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...or Control-C to stop");
Console.ReadLine();
```

After the user hits Enter (or any key really), it prints the next 100 lines...and it goes on like that until the file runs out of lines, then the program stops.

Comment: are you not familiar with setting up a counter..? and doing a conditional `if` statement..? this is not that difficult .. if you are reading the first line outside the loop then lines read would be `1` in your while loop set a lineCnt++ then check if lineCnt = 100, then have them do something else.. come on now..

Answer (score 3):

One approach might be to simply keep track of how many lines you are writing to the console. When you reach 100 lines, stop outputting, wait for input, reset the counter or use %100, and resume the loop.

Answer (score 2):

*using modulo operator*: Use a counter. Initialize it to 0 in the beginning. Increase it after reading each line. And inside the loop have a check like:

```
if (counter % 100 == 0)
  waitForInput();
```

*without modulo operator*: After user clicks enter you can also set counter to 0 - in that case you don't need to use % and can only check

```
 if (counter == 100) {
   waitForInput();
   counter = 0;
 }
```

PS. Something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(__inputfile))
{
    string nextline = tr.ReadLine();
    while (nextline != null)
    {
        counter++;
        if(counter == 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            counter = 0;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(nextline);
        nextline = tr.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(__inputfile))
{
    var count=1;
    string nextline = tr.ReadLine();

    while (nextline != null)
    {
        if (count % 100 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...or Control-C to stop");
            nextline=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(nextline);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nextline);
            nextline = tr.ReadLine();
        }

        count++;
    }
}
```